# What does ‘it’ imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Bad news, Vernon," she said. "Mrs. Figg's broken her leg. She can't
>   take him." She jerked her head in Harry's direction.  Dudley's mouth
>   fell open in horror, but Harry's heart gave a leap. Every year on
>   Dudley's birthday, his parents took him and a friend out for the day,
>   to adventure parks, hamburger restaurants, or the movies. Every year,
>   Harry was left behind with Mrs. Figg, a mad old lady who lived two
>   streets away. Harry hated **it** there. (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

What does ‘it’ imply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence *Harry hated **it** there* can be replaced with one of the following:

> Harry hated **being** there.
>   Harry hated **Mrs Figg's house**.
>   Harry hated **the environment/the feeling/the atmosphere/how he felt when he was** there.
>   Harry hated **everything about Mrs Figg's house**.

There are other possibilities, of course, but these four give you the general idea of what **it** refers to.